# How do I design a 3D Steel IBeam effect on a logo?

Tags: logo, 3d, illustrator-effects, graphic-styles

I have a client that currently has a logo with a 3D effect behind the words. The 3D effect looks like a steel I Beam. They are changing the name of their company and want the same effect behind the new name. How do I create this? I've attached a file with the original effect next to the new effect that I was able to create. I have researched the internet to no avail. [image]

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You need to add some perspective, maybe with the extrude tool

Comment: Hi GraphicsDeptIsMe, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please describe the steps you took to get to your result? That way, it's way easier for us to see how we can help you. Thanks! If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: It's not far off. Perspective and remove the stroke is about the the only difference

Comment: With all my respect. A "steel beam cartoonish" should be not an intrinsec part of the logo. Just a style, maybe.

Comment: Have you tried using a 3d program?

Answer (score 2):

...A steel I-Beam looks like, well an "I". You're using a lowercase "L."

[image]

If they don't care that its an I-Beam or just kinda look like steel beams in general than using Capital letters will probably be your best option. Serif fonts could also help:

[image]

That was done in about 2 seconds right in Photoshop CC2015 with the `New 3D Extrusion from Selected Layer` option.

You could do the same in Illustrator. And then fine tune it however you want with gradients and such.

[image]

But your first issue is trying to make a flat bar (lowercase L) look like a steel beam.

Comment: Hi Ryan! Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this. I really appreciate it. The effect that I was able to create (the lower case l) was done in illustrator. I will give Photoshop a shot and see if it looks better. The original was created in Illustrator so I was trying to just recreate it...but having no luck. Again...thanks for you help! I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: I'm more of a Photoshop guy. Even for a logo I'd probably do it in Photoshop and then trace it in Illustrator. But that's just me. Use whatever tool is going to get the job done correctly and for a logo ultimately it'll need to be in a scalable format. @GraphicsDeptIsMe